# Python AWS boto3 list of instances always updated

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

using AWS Boto3 Resource service i'm getting a list of all my ec2 instance:

```
ec2_instances = ec2.instances.all()
```

every time i'm doing something using my `ec2_instance' variable - it seams to reload the whole instance list..

Is there a way to just pull the list once and then work on it (filter and such)

example of what I do:

**getting the list and showing it as a menu after filtering some values:**

In my Aws() class:

```
    def load_ec2_instance(self, region):
    """
    Load the EC2 instances a region
    :param region:
    :rtype: list
    :return: a list of the instances in a region or None if there are no instances
    """
    ec2 = self._get_resource("ec2", region)
    ec2_instances = ec2.instances.all()
    counter = collections.Counter(ec2_instances);
    ec2_size = sum(counter.itervalues());
    if ec2_size == 0:
        return None
    return ec2_instances
```

in my menu module:

```
       instances = Aws.get_instance().load_ec2_instance(chosen_region)
       show_environments_menu(instances)

        def show_environments_menu(instances):
            subprocess.call("clear")
            print "Please choose the environment your instance is located in:"
            environments = Aws.get_instance().get_environments_from_instances(instances)
            for i, environment in enumerate(environments):
                print "%d. %s" % (i + 1, environment)

        def get_environments_from_instances(self, instances):
        """
        Get all the environments available from instances lists
        :param list instances: the list of instance
        :rtype: list
        :return: a list of the environments
        """
        environments = []
        for instance in instances:
            tags = instance.tags
            for tag in tags:
                key = tag.get("Key")
                if key == "Environment":
                    environment = tag.get("Value").strip()
                    if environment not in environments:
                        environments.append(environment)
        return environments
```

It takes time depending on my internet connection, but I see that when i'm disconnecting my internet - it can't filter.. 
I only have 12 instances so the loop to filter them shouldn't take time at all..

**Update:**
I changed Aws() class to module and i'm using these two functions:

```
def load_ec2_instances(region):
    """
    Load the EC2 instances a region
    :param region:
    :rtype: list
    :return: a list of the instances in a region or None if there are no instances
    """
    ec2 = _get_resource("ec2", region)
    ec2_instances = ec2.instances.all()
    counter = collections.Counter(ec2_instances);
    ec2_size = sum(counter.itervalues());
    if ec2_size == 0:
        return None
    return ec2_instances


def get_environments_from_instances(instances):
    """
    Get all the environments available from instances lists
    :param list instances: the list of instance
    :rtype: list
    :return: a list of the environments
    """
    environments = []
    for instance in instances:
        tags = instance.tags
        for tag in tags:
            key = tag.get("Key")
            if key == "Environment":
                environment = tag.get("Value").strip()
                if environment not in environments:
                    environments.append(environment)
    return environments
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What are you doing with `ec2_instances` variable and why do you think the list is being reloaded every time?

Comment: yes, I added an example to my question

Comment: Could you also post the code for `Aws.get_instance()`? I think the problem may be in this line `environments = Aws.get_instance().get_environments_from_instances(instances)`

Comment: I actually change the structure of Aws from a class to module so now the Aws.get_instance() is not necessary and I just call aws. get_environments_from_instances

Comment: I'm not sure what `get_instance()` method does, but my guess would be that it somehow connects to Amazon servers and that's why you can't filter without internet connection.

Comment: I removed it, I updated the question with the two functions I now use directly...

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still facing this issue

Try using the ec2 client rather than the resource.
Resources in boto3 are higher level and do more work for you whereas the client just gives you what you ask of it.

When you use the client you get python dictionary objects which you can manipulate in memory to your hearts content. See the example below.
You could edit this to use list comprehension and methods etc.

See [EC2.Client.describe_instances](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) for the documentation on the ec2 client method for describing ec2 instances.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name = 'us-west-2')
reservations = ec2.describe_instances()['Reservations']
instances = []
for reservation in reservations:
     for instance in reservation['Instances']:
         instances.append(instance)

environments = []
for instance in instances:
    for tag in instance['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Environment':
            environments.append(tag['Value'])
```